# mysql privileges

Tags: mysql

After executing the following mysql statement to create database and giving privileges to user can't access mysql

```
create database my_db;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_db.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd';
GRANT SELECT ON my_db.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;


mysql -u user -p mypasswd drops me 
Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost'
```

Comment: You given access for user@%. So you can try the below command    **mysql -user@% -p mypasswd**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no space between `-p` and your password.

As you granted rights only for the database `my_db`, add the db also to connect directly to it.

```
mysql -u user -pmypasswd my_db
```

Comment: even like that drops me the same I was trying as well mysql -u user -p than typing the password

Answer (score 1):

You need to give privileges separately for user to connect from localhost. % will not work.

```
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_db.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd';
 GRANT SELECT ON my_db.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd';`
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
GRANT ALL ON my_db.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And afterwards

```
./mysql -uuser -pmypasswd
```

worked ok for me.

If it doesn't, try with localhost:

```
GRANT ALL ON my_db.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```